# Protect traffic originated in remote Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

(newbie Cisco here)

I have an IPSEC vpn site to site tunnel between two ASAs. I have a set of networks in each location protected by the VPN tunnel.

So far, so good.

I would like to also protect traffic originated by the remote ASA, because I have an authentication server on this side.

Thanks!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/346557/what-does-the-cisco-asa-command-management-access-do (pre-dates NE)

Comment: Can you clarify and add a specific question?  Are you having routing issues?

Comment: How can I protect traffic originated on the remote ASA? If I ping from the remote ASA (CLI) , I see it's using the External interface (internet) as source IP, but it's not going through the IPSEC tunnel.

Comment: Not to be nit picky but protect and encrypt are two very different concepts.  Nothing networked is truly protected (e.g. iCloud hack, Fed gov't breach, Iranian Nuclear Power Plant breach, Merkels cell phone tapped, etc.)  Ultimately if you want to protect information, do not store or transmit it in electronic format.  Again, I don't mean to sound nit picky but this is an important point.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

`management-access    Configure management access interface`

In short, that's a the global configuration command to tell the system what interface is used for management (i.e. any traffic generated by the ASA itself.) Cisco's documentation fails to mention that, btw.

Comment: I setup the Internal interface as management-access, but still the source IP is the External interface.

Comment: I assume your aaa-server is defined on "(inside)"?

Comment: My aaa-server is in site A. This ASA is the IPSEC termination in Site B. I want to configure aaa in site B, authenticating against a Radius server residing in Site A.

Answer (score 1):

There was a missing NAT line in the config, so traffic wasn't properly protected.

:-(